# Lebesgue measure and similarities

Tags: geometry, lebesgue-measure

There is a well-known theorem in Euclidean geometry (Eucl. VI-19) that says that *the ratio of the areas of any two similar polygons is equal to the square of the corresponding ratio of similarity*.

In many texts treating the notion of area in the sense of Jordan one can find the analogue of the above result for Jordan measurable subsets of the plane; the theorem in question goes like this:

*Suppose* $R$ *and* $S$ *are Jordan measurable sets such that* $R$ *is similar to* $S$ *under a similarity with dilation factor* $\delta$*. Then,* $\mathrm{area}(R) = \delta^{2} \mathrm{area}(S)$*.*

I wonder if there is an analogue of the above theorem for Lebesgue measurable subsets of the plane...

Let me thank you in advance for your answers, bibliographical suggestions, etc.

Comment: since Lebesgue measure is the unique measure on Borel sets which is equal to the area on rectangles, it's clearly true

Comment: user8268: Would you be so kind as to elaborate on what you've just commented?

Comment: sorry for being cryptic - I meant: if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and you set $\mu(X):=\delta^{-2}\lambda(\delta X)$ then $\mu$ is a measure and it coincides with $\lambda$ on rectangles, so $\mu=\lambda$ by the uniqueness of $\lambda$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

More generally, if $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable and $T$ is a linear mapping, then $\mu(T(A)) = \det(T)\mu(A)$. Also, if $T$ is a translation, then $\mu(T(A)) = \mu(A)$. This implies your statement since any dilation is a composite of a linear mapping and a translation.

See Theorem 2.20 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd Ed.*